# move-to comands in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a variable that is the maximum distance that a turtle can go. This maximum distance is in km. Do I have to convert this variable (maximum distance) to the amount of patch (cell grid) to ask the turtle to move this maximun distance in the world?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. (1) How to move the maximum that a turtle can move? or (2) How to move a specific distance that you need to rescale?

Comment: For example. The turtle can be move maximum 30 meters. My World has each cell 10m. So I need to say the turtle move 3 or move 30 meters or whatever? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the NetLogo distance primitives use distances in patch-widths, so yes you must convert them to real distances.

What I do is define a global parameter "patch-size", which in your case is 10 m: each patch represents a 10x10 m area. (It also makes sense to call this variable "world-resolution" because it means the spatial resolution, or "grain size", of your world is 10x10 m.)

Then divide any distances in m by patch-size. For example, to find patches within 30 m, use: patches in-radius (30 / patch-size).

To get actual distances from NetLogo distances, multiply by patch-size:

```
let distance-to-target (distance the-target) * patch-size
```